# Execute a statement in C for loop together with update statement

Tags: c

The machine code (assembly) after compilation is different. Would the first coding Style increase at least slightly the performance?

```
for(int i=0;i<N;printf("%d\n",(x + i++)));
```

instead of

```
for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
  printf("%d\n",(x + i));
```

Comment: The first is unusual, surprising and therefore hard to read. Avoid it.

Comment: Do you consider microscopically smaller sources files to be a benefit in terms of resources?

Comment: No. There are only drawbacks in terms of readability.

Comment: Yes. You may save your `enter` key.

Comment: @Brian61354270 good point, maybe in an embedded application with limited memory, but I was wondering maybe if the read and write operations of the first coding style are less

Comment: @gigis95 You don't put your *source* code on an embedded system. Unless you are doing something weird...

Comment: why not ? `for(int i=0 ; (i-N) && printf("%d\n",(x + i++)););`

Comment: @gigis95 it does not make the executable smaller. Do you compile on your attiny uC?

Comment: If you are training for the [IOCCC](https://www.ioccc.org) then you are on the right path. Otherwise, it is better to be explicit.

Comment: No benefit. And it violates one programming principle which makes code readable: "one line, one action"

Comment: @0___________ yes my question was mainly for microcontrollers. I am compiling it on a x86 system with gcc and the assembly code files are different so I was thinking whether or not the coding style will affect performance (eg cycles number ).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any benefit in terms of resources coming out of the following
> coding style?
>
> ```
> for(int i=0;i<N;printf("%d\n",(x + i++)));
> ```
>
> instead of
>
> ```
> for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
>   printf("%d\n",(x + i));
> ```

It's unclear exactly what "resources" you might mean, but

- there's no reason to think that one uses less memory than the other, and
- there's no reason to think that one will require more CPU than the other.

In fact, it is plausible (though by no means certain) that a given compiler would compile the two to identical machine code.  For example, you can verify via [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/) that at optimization level -O2, Gcc 12.2 in fact *does* generate identical assembly code for the two variations on the loop.

The former source code is marginally smaller, but the amount of space savings is not significant for modern storage systems, and the cost of the smaller source code is that it is even harder to read and understand than the already-difficult second version.

This is how I would probably write the same code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    printf("%d\n", (x + i));
}
```

Note the additional spaces, which make it easier to pick out the syntactically distinct components, the relatively simpler expressions compared to your first example, and the use of curly braces (`{}`) around the body of the `for` loop, even though it consists of only one statement.

Style preferences do vary, of course, but whatever style you choose should cater to the fact that most code is read many more times than it is written  / modified.  Make your code easy for a human to read and understand.

Comment: I was about to write the same, about curly braces. Speaking of personal preferences, I would also have declared `int i;` before the loop, just to always have a variable declaration at the beginning of a line, instead of it *hiding* in another statement. I found it to be clearer where these declarations lead to shadowing - yes, I know that the inner declaration has a narrow better scope...

Comment: @LuC, as I said, style preferences differ.  Personally, I prefer to declare variables at the narrowest feasible scope, which often means declaring `for` loop iteration variables inside the loop control block.  I am not alone in that regard.

Comment: And I upvote your choice, as I find it a good one

Comment: thanks for your detailed answer, I am using a gcc compiler and the assembly files are a bit different so I was wondering whether the number of cycles or performance would be affected due to micro changes in coding style

Comment: @gigis95, again, focus on writing clear code. Use efficient algorithms.  Having done that, consider micro-optimizations only if your program is not fast enough AND you have evidence that the part you are looking at is a bottleneck.  Sometimes micro-optimizations such as you supposed you might be making provide a small performance boost, but it's very rare for them to provide a significant boost.

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of the final clause in a `for(;;)` statement is to perform - usually mathematical - operations, such as inc-/decrementing loop indices, at the end of the loop.

It is not for performing actions such as `printf()`. Put your regular actions in the loop body - it's where developers expect to find them - and increment the index in the `for(;;)` final clause. You won't lose any efficiency.

**Maintainable** code follows conventional coding vernacular, unless there is a real, pressing reason otherwise. "Because I can" doesn't translate to "Because I should"!

Comment: Your boss my came and say: "you need to rewrite it. But I am not going to pay for it."

Answer (score 1):

The principal reason to put an expression in the third part of the `for` statement instead of as a statement expression in the body of the loop is that a `continue;` statement in the loop will skip further statements in the body of the loop but will not skip the expression in the `for` loop. For example, in:

```
for (i = 0, j = 0; i < N; ++i)
{
    if (SomeTest(i))
        continue;
    ++j;
}
```

the `continue;` will skip the `++j` but will not skip the `++i`. Therefore, `i` will count all iterations, whereas `j` will count only iterations in which the `continue;` was not executed.

Absent a `continue;`, there is no semantic difference in the code; a statement expression at the end of a loop body is executed the same as an expression in the third part of the `for` statement. That leaves only human considerations as reasons to choose between them, notably how expressive they are to human readers.

Answer (score 0):

no significant difference first style with the printf statement inside the for loop condition can be considered less readable and more difficult to understand for someone reading the code.